# Transfer Files From Hidden HDD Macintosh Volume to USB in Recovery Mode From Terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, partition, recovery, hdd

Ok. I am not particularly tech savvy. I am trying to transfer the contents of 2012 Macintosh HDD to a USB drive. My computer crashed and I am trying to recover some files from the Macintosh HDD Volume in the Recovery Mode Terminal.

1. The volume is unmounted and I cannot mount it
2. When I type pwd I get '/volumes'
3. When I type ls -a I get  '.Trashes' 'EFI' and 'OS X Base System'
4. The volume is non repairable
5. diskutil list does not give me a UUID

So, What I am trying to do is reveal this volume, navigate to it, and extract the files.

For the purposes of this question, revealing and accessing the volume are what I am trying to do, as I think I can work out how to copy and paste files once I am in. Just hoping the files are still available in the corrupted volume.

Thanks

Comment: You will need some disk repair software or the ability to edit the disk contents on a level that professional disk recovery specialists charge lots of money for. If this disk is formatted APFS I'm not entirely sure there is *any* software to do data recovery. If it is HFS+ there are a number of repair utilities like DiskWarrior. To reveal this volume to any part of macOS you need to repair the volume, and to repair the volume disk utility needs to be able to see the disk in some way. If it does not there is nothing you can do within macOS to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, will save me lot of pointless tinkering and guesswork. Guess I will have to invest in a disk repair software (it seems to be HFS). Just hope the software can actually repair the volume, as there are a few folders I want to extract.

Comment: I have used DiskWarrior for YEARS and if anything can fix it it can. Know that some disks are beyond repair and there are no guarantees. I have no interest in Alsoft, just a happy and long time customer. Look at Macworld for reviews of disk utilities, and they will have info on others as well. good luck!

Comment: Thanks ;) I'll order Disk Warrior 5.2 Tomorrow and see if it can repair it. If not, time to move on.

Comment: Just remember DW does not work with APFS volumes, so if you have an SSD and Mojave, Catalina it likely won't work.

Comment: HDD, Yosemite. Should be good to go. Just hope it repairs the drive!